# Getting error while runing multiple return statement from cypher query

Tags: php, neo4j, cypher

I'm using neo4j graph db and Is this syntax error or wrong procedure I'm getting some error like this: `array(4) { ["message"]=> string(108093) "Don't know how to treat that as a predicate:` 
my query is

```
       "query" => "match (u : UserProfile {token:{Token}})-[:HAS_SUBSCRIBED]->(upd)-   [:POSTED_UPDATE|PREV*0..]->(sel)
                    return (upd.image OR upd.logo),upd.firstName,upd.uId,sel.content,sel.created skip 0 limit 15",
    "params" => array (
            "Token" => "$token" 
    )
```

I want to return image or logo what ever key users have because same node I'm using for company that has logo and user has image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OR` operator applies to boolean expressions. I guess you want to use the [`COALESCE`](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-functions-scalar.html#functions-coalesce) function which returns the first non-null argument in it's parameter list:

```
...
return coalesce(upd.image, upd.logo), ...
```

Comment: Its working, Thanks alot. Many time you helped me, thanks again @Stefan Armbruster